# Write program for Atmega microcontroller with C#

Tags: atmega, atmel-studio

Anybody know that is there exist a way to write program for **Atmega** microcontroller With **C# language**? Or there is exist a plug in for **Atmel Studio** that add support C# in that IDE?

Comment: I don't **know**, but I think it's very unlikely there's a C# cross compiler for Atmega. As a language it's not really suited to the low level operations such as memory mapped registers you will need to twiddle in the processor.

Comment: Just wondering, Why exactly do you need to program using C# for AVRs?

Comment: Probably not, C# is an compiled JIT language, which means its wasteful. It saves dev time but wastes processor time. Why would you want to waste precious processor time on a microprocessor? Also: Garbage collectors are terrible for real time applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technically not a valid answer to the posted question but it isn't far off.

http://www.netduino.com/

It's not an ATMega but it does support at least one Atmel brand ARM chip (and some STMicro chips too).  It uses VS2013 and a few plugins.

I don't know anything about this platform so I cannot guide you further.  I hope this is close enough to your requirements, but I realise that an ARM is pretty different to the ATMega family.

The .Net Micro framework documentation might have some more information about porting to other chips.

This technology caught my eye a few years back but I never investigated it, might have another look...

Comment: If someone wants to run a scaled down version of the .NET idea on an Arduino-form-factor board, then yes this or its various competitors would be a direction in which to look.  Potentially Intel's Atom-masquerading-as-Arduino boards might be able to run an even more full version, but that would be a relatively large software undertaking if one of the relevant vendors hasn't already done most of the work.

Answer (score 4):

C# requires .NET. It does NOT directly compile out into assembly or machine code. It targets the CLR or one of its subsets. Most C# programmers tend to expect a minimum level of library support, as well.

If you write up a .NET layer on your own (and source code is available) or if you find someone else who has already done it, then you probably could use C#.

There already exists C# for some embedded use, now. I've no idea about ATmega devices, though, nor about the use of Atmel Studio. If I were considering this, I'd simply use Visual Studio and be done with it.

I'd recommend, at first, that you look into the *.NET Micro Framework 4.1* and the *.NET Micro Framework Platform SDK* as a starting point. For example, here is Microsoft's [Overviews of the .NET Micro Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee435387.aspx) as a good page to read. Then I'd probably go search around to see if anyone has attempted an implementation that might be close enough for your interest. I wouldn't expect much, given that you seem focused on the ATmega. .NET is probably easier to implement and better targeted at embedded devices more like the ARM7TDMI, ARM9 and perhaps the Analog Devices' Blackfin.

If you do find something good, though, it may not hurt to provide your own answer here and let all of us know about it.

---

I can see why someone might be interested, coming from a Microsoft VS background and used to using extremely powerful workstation machines, large expanses of memory and almost unlimited persistent storage to back it up with. Extremely powerful software widgets reduce complex tasks to a few simple operations. But an ATmega doesn't have access to such vast resources or raw CPU power.

For example, .NET permits the use of memory files through .NET objects that wrap an underlying support found in the Win32 API. That itself requires the underlying NT functionality. The .NET methods must switch from managed memory to unmanaged Win32 memory resources and theses are then further managed deep in the NT micro kernel. (Win32 is just yet another wrapper for it.) Memory files are really nice for certain needs. And with almost infinite horsepower and infinite memory to play with, many feel the .NET approach is the way to go to keep it "clean" and "easy." Of course, you lose a lot of performance along the way. But who can tell?

On the ATmega, you'd be able to tell.

The handling of anonymous functions, lambdas, closures, early and late binding, reflection, exceptions, reference counting and garbage collection, and... well... these are wonderful things to have access to. But there is a price, too. More than most would be willing to pay with an ATmega trying to drive a few pins for some simple application.

Not to say it cannot be done. I've not tried, so I'm open to the idea it can be done somehow and perhaps even done well enough with a reasoned subset that people might even like and use it. But it seems like a lot of blood, sweat, and tears getting there to me.

Look around though. Some really impressive group might have gotten there. If so, let me know!

Comment: C# is a programming language, like Java or C.  It does NOT require .NET to run, just a CLR implementation. It just so happens that C# is used with the .NET framework 99% of the time.  If you have a micro that can run an implementation of the CLR, then you can compile and run C# code.  I don't know of any micros that actually DO that.  There are micros out there that implement the JVM and allows executing of Java.  There's a distinct difference between a programming language and libraries.

Comment: @CHendrix I mentioned CLR. But I think the OP also expects .NET features. As you point out, 99% of the time! I think we generally agree here.

Answer (score 1):

Let alone the .NET runtime, C# has features which are prohibitive for small MCUs like ATmega. For example, primitive types in C# are impractically large for 8-bit controllers: `int` is 32-bit and `char` is 16-bit. Moreover, C# doesn't have means to explicitly free the memory, fully relying on garbage collection. Allocating internal GC variables will most probably fill up the available RAM before you even have a chance to put a single useful variable there.

There are no 8-bit implementations of C# listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Implementations), and I seriously doubt that such implementations may appear in the future.

Comment: I don't think practicality was high on the agenda when the .Net MF was invented.  Using it on small chips would in most cases require heavy reliance on "unsafe{...}" blocks to get anything done.  Also, some of the ATMegas are pretty capable, one guy managed to boot a linux OS on a ATmega1284p... http://dmitry.gr/index.php?r=05.Projects&proj=07.%20Linux%20on%208bit

Comment: @Wossname Theoretically, all turing-complete machines are equally capable, given infinite time and memory. Practically, I doubt there's any use for an 8-bit ARM emulator, though writing one is certainly a big feat.